# Bodybuilding Young Woman Beats Anorexia Through Exercise

Tags: word-choice, headlinese

Is this correct to say? Bodybuilding Young Woman Beats Anorexia Through Exercise.

Or should I use it this way: Bodybuilding Young Woman Beats Anorexia With Exercise.

Comment: (in response to the close vote) This is not a proofreading question.  It's about *through* versus *with*.  I would prefer not to close this question with that particular close reason.

Comment: This isn't a matter of being "correct", it's a ***stylistic choice*** (where credible alternatives include ***through, with, by, using, via***, etc.).

Comment: Young Woman Bodybuilder Beats Anorexia with Exercise

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would say "through" rather than "with". To me, "through" implies that bodybuilding was more than just a tool, it was a process and an experience she went through that helped her.

Comment: +1. Compare: https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=through+willpower%2Cwith+willpower&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthrough%20willpower%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cwith%20willpower%3B%2Cc0